# Center the caption of e.g. a figure while using a newline

Tags: floats, captions, alignment

I've got the task to write the source of any figure etc. directly in the caption. But it should be placed in a new line and begin at the left hand of the caption (but the caption as it is should be centered) But now the caption just fills the first line with blank characters and therefore it is put to the left side. Any ideas? I'am using the caption package without any setup (Singlelinecheck etc. didnt get me anywhere).

I've integrated the image like this:

`\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4 \textwidth]{Abbildungen/el_Feld_Kondensator}
        \caption{Darstellung des elektrischen Feldes eines Plattenkondensators. \newline (Quelle: \cite{el_Feld_Kondensator})}
        \label{Fig:el_Feld_Kondensator}
  \end{figure}`

The problem is shown in this picture:

[image]

As you see, my whole caption is put on the left side, but it should not.

Comment: For captions several formats has become established. You (explicitly or implicitly) have selected the "hanging" format. Another popular format typesets the caption as a usual paragraph. Depending on your document class there are different approaches to set the caption format. If you share a minimal working example with us we can try to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: I don't believe that the caption "fills the first line with blank characters".  All figure captions I'm familiar with have some blank space defined separating them from the graphic.  So, although it may look like a blank line, it isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant upload anything big, because its written under a blocking note. I can sahre the documentclass setup:

\documentclass[
paper = a4,
fontsize = 12pt,
numbers=noenddot,
%BCOR = 5mm,
headsepline = true,
footsepline = true,
plainfootsepline = true,
%appendixprefix,
parskip,                
listof = totoc,
bibliography = totoc,
index = totoc,
twoside = false
]{scrreprt}

And I've integrated the caption  package via this command: \usepackage{caption}.